# Exported SVG graphic has numbers along edges

Tags: graphics, export, svg-format

I'm trying to export a stream plot to an SVG grapic.  I make the stream plot like this:

```
g = StreamPlot[{-x, y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

Then export it like this

```
Export["stream.svg", g]
```

But the resulting image has large numbers along its sides:

[image]

Why are these so much larger than in the notebook?

Comment: I am not seeing this in v10.1 under Windows.  What version and platform are you using, and what are you using to render the SVG file?

Comment: I'm using 10.3.1.0 on macOS Sierra and rendering them in inkscape. Setting FrameTicks-> None, as recommended below, gets rid of the numbers, though it doesn't explain why the numbers are so much larger in the SVG than they are in the Mathematica notebook labels for the ticks

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in Mma 11.1.1.

Comment: Hmm maybe it's just my version then? Strange.

Comment: It's just a bug which is fixed in version 11.1. You're original question, namely how to work around it in a version where the bug is present, was more interesting.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem both with *Mathematica* 11.0.1 and 11.1.1 on Windows 7 x64: the SVG is rendered nicely both by IE and Firefox. But importing into Illustrator 17 shows similar problem with font sizes and placement of the tick labels in the both versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the numbers using `FrameTicks -> None`

```
g = StreamPlot[{-x, y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, FrameTicks -> None]

Export["stream.svg", g]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But your problem seems to be that the numbers are oversized.

---

**UPDATE**
The question was edited. Unfortunately I can't reproduce the problem in *Mathematica 11.1.1*. I suggest  you have a play with the fonts.

```
g = StreamPlot[{-x, y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
    FontTracking -> "Plain", TextJustification -> 0, 
    PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}}]
```

---

<sub>Code and plots done in *Mathemathica 11.1.1* on Win7</sub>

Comment: Yes exactly. Thanks for the suggestion; this will allow me to do what I want.  But it still doesn't answer why the numbers are so oversized.

Comment: @user51688 I know, but the question was *"How can I get rid of these?"*

Comment: Edited for clarity :)

Comment: @user51688 Next time please think you question carefully. [It's discouraging to have a moving target](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/10397)